# Filtering products index in elasticsearch by user

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

I have an index of products. They have regular fields such as id, name, brand etc. Querying this index is working great, however I want to limit the products which are returned for specific users.

Say I have 5 products who’s IDs go from 1-5

```
Id: 1, name: “Product One”, brand: “Fake Brand”
Id: 2, name: “Product Two”, brand: “Fake Brand”
Id: 3, name: “Product Three”, brand: “Fake Brand”
Id: 4, name: “Product Four”, brand: “Fake Brand”
Id: 5, name: “Product Five”, brand: “Fake Brand”
```

If there’s no filter, and I search for brand: “Fake Brand”, I get 5 results.

But I want to add this functionality: Say I have two users. User 1 is only able to “see” product IDs 1, 2, and 5. And User 2 is only able to “see” a different subset, say, product IDs 1, 2, 4 and 5.

So if user 1 searches for brand: “Fake Brand”, he only gets back product with IDs 1, 2, and 5. Where as if user 2 searches for brand: “Fake Brand”, he only gets back products with IDs 1, 2, 4 and 5.

Is there a way to add a “user id” to this products query and then store somewhere else what products a user is able to see?

In SQL I would probably have a different table storing what products each user can see and then just do a join. But using ES I think I either have to have two separate indexes or to use nested or has_child/has_parent queries but I’m not entirely sure how to implement it.